# Cannot find mail folder

Tags: mail.app, email, spotlight

For some reason I cannot find my folder v10 folder where my mails are stored. I wanted to reindex my my mails als client is (again) stuck at "copying messages..." but in my ~/Library/mail folder there is only v2 and v3 nothing else.

I'm using 13" 2020 M1 macbook pro with Ventura 13.3.1 and Mail 16.0

I've been searching through my mac for days now and can't find the mail data. They must be somewhere as they display in the mail app.. no spotlight search helped either.. all returns zero

[image]

Comment: 1) "no spotlight search helped either" - sadly expected because Spotlight doesn't index Mail like it indexes most files. 2) Try this: In Activity Monitor open (double click) the Mail app and look at "Open Files and Ports" tab. Look for a V10 folder.

Comment: 3) Use Find Any File https://findanyfile.app to look for something called V10.

Comment: Can't you just use "Rebuild Mailbox" from the menu?

Comment: Thanks, @Gilby the activity monitor helped.. for some reason the files are stored here

~/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/

Thanks also for the findanyfile.app tip. WIll come in handy.